# Cross-Group.SE Questions: Logic-friendly keyboards

Tags: discussion, support

Where's a better place to ask about how to easily include existential and universal quantifiers, and other common logic symbols, when typing on an iOs device?

Here, where people will know how to recognize a good solution, or a more tech-savvy group, which might be more familiar with the practical details of remapping keyboards in general?

This is a specific question, but I felt it was a little too meta. I'm also curious to hear any LaTex horror stories and workarounds people may use, even just .Xmodmap files or what anyone thinks would be the most effective logic-friendly keyboard map.

Comment: The Apple stack might have suggestions.